# Google Chrome HTML5 Video fails to download if "src" is a redirect URL to a different domain

Tags: google-chrome, download, html5-video

I have problem with native "download" button in Google Chrome HTML5 Video.

If <video> has <source> with "src" URL that redirects to an URL with different domain, Google Chrome fails to download the video with **Failed - Network error**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN1PM.png). Redirect URL is a public URL that is accessible by everyone, so no issues with authentication or security.

**Apache config:**

```
# site1
<VirtualHost *:8889>
        ServerName local.site1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        RedirectMatch "^/video.mp4" "http://local.site2.com:8889/video.mp4"
</VirtualHost>

# site2
<VirtualHost *:8889>
        ServerName local.site2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Site1 index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <video width="300px" height="300px" preload="none" controls="">
      <source src="/video.mp4">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apache log when I click Download:

```
local.site1.com:80 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2020:10:06:31 +0600] "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 302 566 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Note: removing **preload="none"** can fix the issue, but I need it to be set in my case.

PS. If I click Play button first, Chrome sends GET request, receives redirect URL and plays the video and then I am able to download the video.

PS2. I checked without redirection with different domain URL in "src" attribute and I was able to download video without errors.

Is this a Google Chrome bug? Is it possible to fix?